# opencv+python: Assertion failure when findcontours

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on an image processing project.

I am using opencv 2.4.11 + python 2.7

The code is simple as

```
def preprocessing(src):
    src = cv2.resize(src, (0,0), fx=6, fy=6)
    kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)

    dilate = cv2.dilate(src, kernel, iterations = 1)
    erode = cv2.erode(dilate, kernel, iterations = 1)

    cv2.imshow("dilate", dilate)
    cv2.imshow("erode", erode)

    th, thresh = cv2.threshold(erode, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2.drawContours(src,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)

    cv2.imshow("src", src)
    cv2.waitKey()


print "==== start image processing ====="
im2 = cv2.imread("training1.png",cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
preprocessing(im2)
```

But the findcontours returns assertion failure

The output is

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (step[dims-1] == (size_t)CV_ELEM_SIZE(flags)) in create, file /tmp/opencv20160107-29960-t5glvv/opencv-2.4.12/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 236
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process.py", line 55, in <module>
preprocessing(im2)
  File "process.py", line 44, in preprocessing
contours, hierarchy =  cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.error: /tmp/opencv20160107-29960-t5glvv/opencv-2.4.12/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:236: error: (-215) step[dims-1] == (size_t)CV_ELEM_SIZE(flags) in function create
```

Can anyone help? Thank you very much

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Sorry for that. I have finished indented.

Comment: (a) The error message does not match the code shown.  (b) The code, as shown, works fine for me.

Comment: @John1024 sorry, i just pick part of the code here. And what version of python and opencv are you using? I found the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922944/error-when-using-cv2-findcontours

Comment: Python 2.7.9 and opencv 2.4.9

Comment: @John1024 But how can it output the correct result from previous functions. And if I just remove the png from the directory. The cv2.resize() function will throw the exception.

Comment: You are right. The errors are different.  Hmm.

Comment: What does `im2.dtype` show?

Comment: @John1024 It's unit8

Comment: OK.  `uint8` is the same as the images I was using.  I have no more ideas.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for help. I am following the same question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806879/function-calchist-in-opencv-crashing-in-python-on-mac I guess there are mistakes or bugs in the dev environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

1. Unlink opencv from brew.
2. Download  Anaconda package: http://continuum.io/downloads#all and install.
3. Install openCV: "conda install opencv" which is version 2.4.8.

If there is anaconda conflict with bottleneck, remove the reference and install it again by conda install command.

I still don't know why opencv 2.4.12 throws such exception, I guess it is because the numpy is conflict against opencv.

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine. The reason is that the image file is missing.

Comment: But how did I get results from previous imshow() function? Is that a bug for opencv?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the image into gray scale and then try contour .It worked for me